# MSBUILD build a project WITH the XML documentation files

Tags: msbuild

This should be easy, but I can't get it to work.

I have a web project, that references another project in my solution (lets call it Project1). Both projects are set to create XML documentation files.

When I right click the web project and build in Visual studio, my `web/bin` folder contains the XML doc files for both the web project and Project1.

I want exactly the same behavior in MSBUILD, so when I build I get both XML files in the bin folder, but I can't get it to play ball - what happens is that the XML file for the web project is created, but not for project1.

I've tried

- `MSBUILD` the solution
- `MSBUILD` the web project
- `/p:GenerateDocumentation=true` doesn't work (on the solution or the web proj)

Help!

Comment: "doesn't work" isn't very descriptive - do you get *no* XML? Or just the XML files for one project but not the other? Something else?

Comment: @MattRoberts it works on my machine. File -> New web app followed my msbuild generates the xml. check the documentation output path for both debug an release. Msbuild does a Debug build by default so I would guess that your debug output path is not the bin folder. Might be wrong :)

Comment: Cheers @CosminOnea - you were on the right track - I added my own answer below!

Answer (score 10):

Gah. I got it.

I was specifying the `Configuration` (`/p:Configuration=Release`) but not a platform (`/p:Platform="Any CPU"`). So, it was choosing the `x64 platform` which is a platform I'd not ticked build XML documentation for.

TLD: Make sure you specify the configuration and the platform for the solution, and the XML docs will be created!

Comment: This answer is incomplete. You need to provide p:GenerateDocumentation and optionally p:DocumentationFile https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb629394.aspx

Answer (score 4):

On my end the XML was generated when building locally in VS, but NOT using MSBuild Task on TFS / Azure DevOps.

The "magic" part is to specify the `p:/DocumentationFile` parameter.
In my working scenario it is:  `/p:DocumentationFile="$(ApplicationName).xml"`

Thus the file comes out to the output directory along with project dlls.